# c# equivalent to pythons 'a in [1, 2, 3]'

Tags: c#, python, syntax

Is there an equivalent to python's `a in [1, 2, 3]` in C#?

I've tried `new int[]{1, 2, 3}.Contains(a)` -- which is lot uglier, but does the same.

Of course, I could also do, `(a==1 || a==2 || a==3)` but with different variables and namespaces, this can get a bit clunky too.

Comment: Maybe (a>=1 && a<=3) ?

Comment: I have to check 1,2,4,6,8

Comment: so you are just looking for another option that just "looks nice" for the compiler?

Comment: Personally, I do `validValues.Contains(val)`. Not sure if there's a prettier way though

Answer (score 7):

Just throwing this out there and is completely untested.

```
public static bool In(this object obj, params object[] items)
{
    return items.Any(o => o.Equals(obj));
}
```

I think the extension method would be what you are looking for and then just tweak the actual comparison check to suit your needs. I went with object so it would work with anything, but you can be more specific if you'd like.

Just call it like so:

```
if (4.In(1,2,3,4))
{
    // Do something
}
```

You could change this to take in an IEnumerable, but if you already have one then probably best to just call .Contains() or .Any() on your collection.

Comment: It would be nice if something like this were built in!